# Formatting a LaTeX article to look really good

Tags: formatting

I have been using LaTeX to write scientific articles for about 6-months now. I know quite well now how to manipulate and create great content but don’t really understand the formatting/style side to Latex. I need to submit a document soon which I want to make it look really good and professional much like this Nature article:

http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v424/n6950/pdf/nature01935.pdf

I want to know more specifically how to:

- Colour titles
- Add a background frame to all figures and captions
- Drop cap the first letter of the introduction

I know this question is very general but any help or pointers of how or where I could find out would be much appreciated! Are there templates on-line which you can download and just apply to your document for these sort of things?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This site works best if you ask one question at the time.

Comment: I'd say that a submission would look more professional if it *doesn't* try looking like a published paper.

Comment: @egreg Agreed. I don't think the linked article looks very professional. Also, maybe I just don't have the right font installed, but the letter spacing makes the linked article practically illegible.

Comment: @Josh The pdf of the nature article you are referring to, hides behind a paywall. Only people surfing from inside an university network are probably able to see it.

Comment: As this question stands, it is too vague to be a 'good' question. Individual requirements, such as 'boxed' floats, coloured titles, _etc._, make good focussed questions, and some have already been dealt with here.

Answer (score 7):

If you know a title of the journal to which you want to submit the article you can check if they provide their own macros. Some journals will give you macros they expect you to use. That will enable you to see the paper in the exact form in which it is going to appears in the journal (of course if accepted).

Answer (score 2):

You could visit [CTAN](http://ctan.org/) and [search](http://ctan.org/search) for `nature`.

And you will find the [nature class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nature/):
Prepare papers for the journal Nature.

(I have not checked, if it is correct, but it sounds good).

Comment: Nature are not keen on LaTeX: I wonder how useful this will be!

Comment: Actually, one of their journals, Nature Physics, is typeset by LaTeX. The author guidelines say to use a standard class, e.g., article.cls or revtex.cls, and they ask the authors to "use the default Computer Modern fonts".  So using a special class or trying to imitate the format of a published article is entirely unnecessary; it might even interfere with their production process.